# using single quotes in string for xslt document() function

Tags: java, xslt

I'm trying to send a SQL string to URI resolver via XSLT document() function. The transformer fails when I use single quotes in it. Does anybody what to use in this sitation?

Here is the code from XSL file

```
<xsl:variable name="findFEV" select="document('sql:select md from MenuData md where md.id=194003 and string01='David' and md.account = :account')"/>
```

This is the error that I get when I run transformation.

```
15:59:12,165 ERROR [STDERR] javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Expected ,, but found: David
15:59:12,165 ERROR [STDERR] javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Expected ,, but found: David
15:59:12,166 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:938)
15:59:12,167 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:776)
15:59:12,167 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.tolven.api.rs.resource.DataExtractResources.transform(DataExtractResources.java:109)
15:59:12,167 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
15:59:12,167 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
15:59:12,168 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
15:59:12,168 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
15:59:12,168 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:186)
```

Comment: Due to no good `'David'` Try `\'David\'` - not sure. Or `&apos;David&apos;` should do.

Comment: @JoopEggen Nope. I tried that already. It didn't help.

Comment: You have to replace the single quotes with `&apos;` (so `&apos;David&apos;`)

Comment: @DanielHaley I get the same error.  16:28:13,091 ERROR [STDERR] javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Expected ,, but found: David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="findFEV"
select='document("sql:select md ... and string01=&apos;David&apos; and ...")'/>
```

Explanation:

The select expression will become

```
document("sql:select md ... string01='David' and ...")
```

which fits. The document call needs a double quoted string as `'David'` has to be in single quotes (SQL).

Thanks to @DanielHaley